# vee-validate 3 + nuxt show errors only on submit

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I'm having a hard time figuring out form validation that only triggers the errors upon submit.
The main reason I don't want to show inline errors are because of this article which insinuates inline errors provide a worse user experience than providing the error messages upon submit:

https://uxmovement.com/forms/why-users-make-more-errors-with-instant-inline-validation/

Even though the vee-validate 3 docs state that validating before submit is a "must":

https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#basic-example

Unfortunately this post cover vee-validate 2 and not 3:

[How do I stop displaying the inline validation error message in Vuetify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189201/how-do-i-stop-displaying-the-inline-validation-error-message-in-vuetify)

This post talks about catching the errors on submit, however I don't understand how I would disable the errors before submit:
[Vee Validate 3 catch errors on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935108/vee-validate-3-catch-errors-on-form-submit)

Vee-validate 2 had somewhat clear instructions regarding this but I cannot seem to find it in Vee-validate 3 docs:
https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/events.html#changing-events-per-field

I'm using Vuetify and Nuxt, and have registred vee-validate in my plugins:

```
import { extend } from "vee-validate";
import { required, email } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";

extend("required", {
    ...required,
    message: "This field is required"
});

extend("email", {
  ...email,
  message: "This field must be a valid email"
});
```

My form code:

```
 <ValidationObserver
    ref="form"
    v-slot="{ invalid, validated, handleSubmit, validate }"
  >
    <v-form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <ValidationProvider
        name="email"
        rules="required|email"
        v-slot="{ errors, valid }"
      >
        <v-text-field
          v-model="email"
          :error-messages="errors"
          :success="valid"
          label="E-mail"
          required
        ></v-text-field>
      </ValidationProvider>

      <ValidationProvider
        name="password"
        rules="required|max:50"
        v-slot="{ errors, valid }"
      >
        <v-text-field
          v-model="password"
          :counter="50"
          type="password"
          :error-messages="errors"
          :success="valid"
          label="Password"
          required
        ></v-text-field>
      </ValidationProvider>
    
      <v-btn color="primary" type="submit">Submit</v-btn>
    </v-form>
```

Script section:

```
<script>
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from "vee-validate";
export default {
  components: {
    ValidationObserver,
    ValidationProvider,
  },
  data: () => ({
    password: "",
    email: "",
  }),

  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.$refs.form.validate().then((success) => {
        if (!success) {
          // run your error code here
        }

        alert("Form has been submitted!");
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The submit would trigger the errors but it doesn't prevent them from showing up inline as well.
Appreciate all feedback&replies, I guess my last resort is to switch to vee-validate 2 but here's hoping someone knows how it's done in vee-validate 3.

**Edit:**

The only solution I could come up with is setting hide-details="" on the fields which covers the error message up but not the red underline, only to attach a span below which is triggered by a v-if. I doubt this is a good solution though and would love to update it.

```
<v-text-field
              v-model="email"
              :error-messages="errors"
              :success="valid"
              label="E-mail"
              required
              hide-details=""
            ></v-text-field>
             <span v-if="submitted">{{errors[0]}}</span>
```

Comment: try add `@input="$refs.form.validate()" & @blur="$refs.form.validate()"` in your `textfield` slot

Answer (score 1):

You can set the interaction mode to be `passive`, which doesn't validate on any event. This is mentioned in the docs in the `interaction and ux` section. This is the equivalent to `events` in v2.

https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/interaction-and-ux.html#passive

Comment: It seems that `passive` mode was removed in vee-validate v4 for some reason

Comment: Yes, but you can implement it with the composition API in v4: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/examples/dynamic-validation-triggers/